# Data type Identification showing wrong output MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to check if the value that has been entered by the users are Integer or not. I tried to using the below code, but it gives me the wrong output. When I entered a fractional value, it still shows me "it is an Integer".

```
prompt = {'Please Enter the start time:','Increment:','Stop time:'}; %Asking user to enter the data
dlgtitle = 'Input'; %Creating a title for the dialog box
dims = [1 40]; %Adjusting the dimensions
definput = {'0','0.01','10'}; %Using default values to warn users not to put text instead of number
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlgtitle,dims,definput); %storing the three items of data the user enters
start = str2num(answer{1}); %Converting start value string to number
increment = str2num(answer{2}); %Converting increment value string to number
stop = str2num(answer{3}); %Converting stop value string to number



if start >= stop
    f = msgbox('Start time cannot be greater than end time! Please re-enter!', 'Error!');

elseif increment >= stop
    f = msgbox('The increment cannot be larger than the end time! Please re-enter!', 'Error!');
elseif start <= -1 
    f = msgbox('The start time can only be positive numbers! Please re-enter!', 'Error!' );
elseif stop <= -1 
    f = msgbox('The end time can only be positive numbers! Please re-enter!', 'Error!');
elseif increment <= -1 
    f = msgbox('The increment can only be positive numbers! Please re-enter!', 'Error!');
elseif isempty(str2num(answer{1}))
    f = msgbox('Input must be a number! Please re-enter!', 'Error!');
elseif isempty(str2num(answer{2}))
    f = msgbox('Input must be a number! Please re-enter!', 'Error!');
elseif isempty(str2num(answer{3}))
    f = msgbox('Input must be a number! Please re-enter!', 'Error!');
end 

start=int16(10); %define 'count' as an 8-bit integer 
integer_check=isinteger(start)% is count an integer, 1 if yes, 0 if no 
    if integer_check==1 % if isinteger returns a ‘1’ display message
          disp(' Yes it is an integer')
    else                  % if isinteger returns a ‘0’ display message
            disp(' No it is not an integer')
    end
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to include the current output and why that's not as desired?

Comment: I did it. Hope that helps

Comment: `start=int16(10)` is always an integer, no matter what values are input earlier.

Answer (score 2):

If is an integer, it doesn’t have a remainder if is divided over 1. So, instead of
`integer_check = isinteger(start)`

Use

```
integer_check = rem(start,1) == 0;
```

Comment: This would be a great answer if you also explain why `isinteger(1)` is false.

Comment: Looking in the documentation of matlab about integers (int16) https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html , when a double is converted to int16, Matlab stores the decimals somewhere . See the hyperlink, there is an example where a double with decimals is converted to int16 and then add 0.001 and the values changes.

Comment: The isinteger funtion only checks that the variable is an integer data type. The decimals are still there.

Comment: `1` is a double. The value is integer, but the type is not. `isinteger` indeed only looks at the type, not at the value. This has nothing to do with decimals, and no, MATLAB does not secretly store decimals when you cast to integer.